# Check if string contains a certain amount of words of another string

Tags: python, string

Say we have a string 1 `A B C D E F` and a string 2 `B D E` (The letters are just for demo, in reality they are words). Now I would like to find out if there are any `n` conscutive "words" from string 2 in string 1. To convert the string to "words", I'd use `string.split()`.

For example for `n` equals 2, I would like to check whether `B D` or `D E` is - **in this order** - in string 1. `B D` is not in this order in the string, but `D E` is.

Does anyone see a pythonic way of doing this?

I do have a solution for `n` equals 2 but realized that I need it for arbitrary n. Also it is not particularily beautiful:

```
def string_contains_words_of_string(words_str, words_to_check_str):
    words = words_str.split()
    words_to_check = words_to_check_str.split()

    found_word_index = None
    for word in words:
        start = 0 if found_word_index is None else found_word_index + 1
        for i, word_to_check in enumerate(words_to_check[start:]):
            if word_to_check == word:
                if found_word_index is not None:
                    return True
                found_word_index = i
                break
            else:
                found_word_index = None
    return False
```

Comment: just want to be clear. In the description, you said you have two string, but in the code you have two list of string. Do you give more explanation on it?

Comment: I updated my question & the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy with a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> st1='A B C D E F'
>>> st2='B D E'
>>> n=2
>>> pat=r'(?=({}))'.format(r's+'.join(r'\w+' for i in range(n)))
>>> print [(s, s in st1) for s in re.findall(pat, st2)]
[('B D', False), ('D E', True)]
```

The key is to use a zero width look ahead to find overlapping matches in the string. So:

```
>>> re.findall('(?=(\\w+\\s+\\w+))', 'B D E')
['B D', 'D E']
```

Now build that for `n` repetitions of the word found by `\w+` with:

```
>>> n=2
>>> r'(?=({}))'.format(r's\+'.join(r'\w+' for i in range(n)))
'(?=(\\w+\\s+\\w+))'
```

Now since you have two strings, use Python's `in` operator to produce a tuple of the result of `s` from the regex matches to the target string.

---

Of course if you want a non-regex to do this, just produce substrings n words by n:

```
>>> li=st2.split()
>>> n=2
>>> [(s, s in st1) for s in (' '.join(li[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(li)-n+1))]
[('B D', False), ('D E', True)]
```

And if you want the index (either method) you can use [str.find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
>>> [(s, st1.find(s)) for s in (' '.join(li[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(li)-n+1)) 
...     if s in st1]
[('D E', 6)]
```

---

For regex that goes word by word, make sure you use a word boundary anchor:

```
>>> st='wordW wordX wordY wordZ'
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(\b\w+\s\b\w+))', st)
['wordW wordX', 'wordX wordY', 'wordY wordZ']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The regex unfortunately only works for the described case of single letters, not when those single letters are entire words because then Eat Meat is divided into ('Eat Meat', 'at meat', 't meat') because the regex does not specify that the previous character should be a \w too. any idea on how to do this?

Comment: @fabian789: Use `\b` word boundary anchor. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

you could build ngrams like so:

```
a = 'this is an example, whatever'.split()
b = 'this is another example, whatever'.split()

def ngrams(string, n):
    return set(zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)]))

def common_ngrams(string1, string2, n):
    return ngrams(string1, n) & ngrams(string2, n)
```

results:

```
print(common_ngrams(a, b, 2))
{('this', 'is'), ('example,', 'whatever')}

print(common_ngrams(a, b, 1))
{('this',), ('is',), ('example,',), ('whatever',)}
```

Note that the tricky bit is in the ngrams function with the [zip function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)]
```

This is essentialy the same as

```
zip(string, string[1:], string[2:])
```

for n = 3.

Also note that we're using sets of tuples, this is the best performance wise...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two strings (this can as easily be solved for strings containing more than just one letter each)

```
a = 'this is a beautiful day'
b = 'this day is awful'
```

Then to get all the words of b that also belong to a you write

```
x = [x for x in b.split() if x in a.split()]
```

Now x contains (after one line of code)

```
['this', 'day', 'is']
```

Then you check whether the serial combinations of x (from 0 up `len(x)`) belong in b

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(i, len(x)+1):
        word = ' '.join(x[i:j])
        if word in b:
            print(word)
```

The [**Example**](http://ideone.com/pILblz) prints the (order preservig) combinations of `b`'s words that are also present in `a` in the same order (it takes a small tweak in the `if` statement of the nested for)

Answer (score 0):

The [longest common substring algorithm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Python) will work here, if you pass in a split list instead of a plain string - with the added bonus that it will also give the longest string made from the longest run of characters if you pass in the unsplit string.

```
def longest_common_substring(s1, s2):
    m = [[0] * (1 + len(s2)) for i in xrange(1 + len(s1))]
    longest, x_longest = 0, 0
    for x in xrange(1, 1 + len(s1)):
        for y in xrange(1, 1 + len(s2)):
            if s1[x - 1] == s2[y - 1]:
                m[x][y] = m[x - 1][y - 1] + 1
                if m[x][y] > longest:
                    longest = m[x][y]
                    x_longest = x
            else:
                m[x][y] = 0
    return s1[x_longest - longest: x_longest]
```